# python printing each character in new line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to print lines and replace words in lines of a text/html file but not able to do so because python (2.7) is reading it character by character. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code and output:

```
import sys

infile = open('filenmae').read()

for line in infile:
    print line
```

The output I should get (only first line displayed here):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

The output I'm getting:

```
<
!
D
O
C
T
Y
P
E
.
.
.
```

Comment: hint 1: iterating over a file will give you a line each time, and iterating over a string gives you a character each time. hint 2: `infile` is not a file, it's a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try `file.readlines()` instead as follows:

```
infile = open('filename').readlines()
for line in infile:
    print line
```

This loops over each line rather than each character in the file.

`Output: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">`

Comment: @PreritAhuja: Glad you found both answers to be helpful; sorry, you can only mark **one** as accepted.

Answer (score 10):

You are looping over a single string, which yields individual characters.

Don't read the file in one go, just loop over the file object:

```
with open('filename') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print line
```

I used the file as a context manager here as well (`with open(..) as localname`); Python will now automatically close the file for you when the `with` block is exited.

Looping over the file object reads lines as needed, avoiding reading the whole file into memory.

Other alternatives are to read the file in one go as separate lines with the [`file.readlines()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines):

```
infile = open('filename').readlines()
```

or to split the read data with [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
infile = open('filename').read().splitlines()
```

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation. I've been looking for this for some time already :-)

Comment: Definitely the best and most complete answer here